# Trouble installing signed driver after installing unsigned driver

Tags: installation, driver

I have many clients that use com0com which is a virtual port driver on 64 bit systems.  There are a few versions of this driver but only one older one that is signed.
Now if you use the versions I suggest then it installs with no problem.  Driver is signed as it should be.  However, if you first install an unsigned version of the driver (in other words you didn't read the manual!!), then of course it doesn't get installed.  However, from that point on, the good ones with signing can never be installed.  The installation then says that the drivers are not signed.
It seems nothing can be done to rectify this.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Solved...Windows kept picking the old driver.  Deleting it in the Device Manager fixed it.